# WCF REST Solution , Avoiding using the port number in URI

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I have a WCF REST Service listening from two different ports, one for regulars HTTP request and the other for HTTPS request. It works fine and everything was working in proper way, this is a service that is exposed to the Internet.

Here is the Issue: When a user performs a call back from VPN (Cisco VPN) or some office networks, the service is unreachable, I did some research, and what I realized it seems either the VPN and the Firewall or Proxy in the Office does not allows to call URI with a port embeded, (https://domain:[port]/service.svc), My hence focused in doing a kind of Routing thing (WCF 4.0 Routing) , in order to avoid the use of port, it didnt work , is there any way to avoid using the port?. I would really appreciate any idea

Comment: your WCF service runs on which port?

Comment: If you are using the default ports, 80 and 443, for http and https you shouldn't need to specify the port in the url.

Comment: Im using diferent ports, not default ports , for security reasons and the fact to use the same server-box

Comment: Hi Chetan , it Runs this way : my website  consumes the WCF REST service the WEBSITE runs over 80 , 443 Port for HTTP and HTTPS , WCF i set up over (55300) port (SSL) protected. Same box :(